# okta authentification through python for parsing

Tags: python, urllib, okta, okta-api

My company just implemented a okta authentification to access to the intranet. I used a script to parse some part of the intranet to syntetize some news but since okta authentification has been implemented, I cannot be connected to the intranet.
The only things I get trying to get the page is login to okta...

Has someone already deal with this problem ?
I tried used https://github.com/okta/oktasdk-python/tree/master/okta but apparently not useful for my need.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is to write some code in Python that will synthesize, or process, data from a website on your intranet. Further, it seems that this intranet site is secured by Okta and you are having trouble connecting to the intranet site.

If I understood the question correctly, I suspect that the problem you are having is that the intranet site is secured via SAML. There are typically two ways to handle situations like this:

1. (Ideal) See if the intranet site has an API you can use with an API token.
2. Write code in Python to handle the SAML flow and get a cookie to the intranet site. If you are using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), this will mostly mean writing code to authenticate with Okta and follow the SAML redirects, using a [Session](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) in Requests to keep track of your cookies for you.